# How do I get a builtin Sharepoint property in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, sharepoint, properties

I am trying to get a property from a workbook that has Sharepoint properties inside an Excel Workbook. I can use **ThisWorkbook.ContentTypeProperties("Example")** to get a property that was created in Sharepoint. It does not however find any property for **Version** and **ID**.

So since its not ContentTypeProperties, CustomTypeProperties or BuiltinDocumentProperties how can I retrieve Version and ID in Excel?

Thank you for reading.